# Python style question, function parameters

Tags: python, coding-style

Which is preferred

```
def method(self):
```

or

```
def method( self ):
```

With spaces in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  It says to do the first one.

Answer (score 9):

The common reference for Python style is PEP8, see: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

To answer your question specifically, this is under "Pet Peeves":

Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:

- Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces.

  - Yes: spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2})
  - No:  spam( ham[ 1 ], { eggs: 2 } )

Answer (score 3):

There's PEP 8 the Python Style Guide:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

It suggests the former style, but note the introduction carefully.

I find the latter to be visual nails-on-chalkboard, personally.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

[Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

No space around the inside of function signatures.  Occasionally I put space inside the parens of a function *call* if the arguments are particularly hairy, but never on the definition.  I don't think any language makes a habit of that, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should blindly follow the PEP-8 style, like a vow upon a bible.

The PEP8 is intended for code that goes in the *python standard library*, i.e. the modules you can import just after you've installed Python, but they have very different development constraints than most of the software I write.

So I tend to think a lot about each "rule" (either from the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857)/[pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) ones, or the [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)) and see how it can apply to my code -- the pros and cons.

As for your question, people usually don't use spaces inside parentheses, although I've seen it in some code by coworkers that like it, IMHO it detracts a little from readability, but it's a minor issue.

Comment: From the first section of PEP 8: "But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply."